# How does a WooCommerce site integrate with the existing real world customer members?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, members, plugin-members

I have an ordinary website (no WooCommerce function), and now adding woocommerce plugin to enable it with selling functions.

Now I have some existing customer members from the real-world shop, how to add these real-world members to this “new online shop with woocommerce plugin”? so that these old member can enjoy some privileges in this online shop.

Do I need to buy one more "WooCommerce Subscriptions Plugin" to incorporate it?

Comment: What sort of privileges? If you're thinking of using the subscriptions plugin do you mean you're selling access to the site?

Comment: Thank you @Rup, nope, at the movement, all the new and old members will be free members. Just now i have 2000 old members from my brick and mortar shops, and i wanna put them in my new wordpress site. I don't know how to put them in, and most importantly to notify them automatically in bulk by email with their new login, and get them change their own password. 

The privilege will be a special discount for the online products...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread that: I thought you meant people who already had a login to an existing WordPress site. I'd look for a bulk create users plugin or import from CSV plugin to do the actual import - there's a few, haven't used one to recommend it sorry. You need to give all the imported users the role 'customer'.

Comment: I'm not sure how to set up the discounts though: do you have code or a plugin that will give per-user discounts already? How you configure the users for that will depend on that code: maybe it's a different role, or maybe it's some user_meta that you set on the user.

Comment: thank you @Rup, your answer is helpful, i will keep looking for the answer.